# cv-qualifiers and rvalue-reference

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose we have this piece of code shown as below, the question is that why the cv qualifier (const) for "c" is not kept which the behavior is distinct from "v"?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int x{};
  int y{};
  const auto [v] = std::tuple<int>(x);
  const auto [c] = std::tuple<int&&>(std::move(y));
  decltype(v) vv = 10;  // vv -> const int;
  decltype(c) cc = 100; // cc -> int&&;
  return 0;
}
```

Also, can I mimic the same type deduction process with template argument deduction somehow like below?

```cpp
template<class T> 
void foo(T t) {  // here should be T rather than universal reference;
  // mimic the same behavior as above somehow ...
}
```

**Doubt 2:**

For the code as below, it seems the "auto" inference for "Structured Binding" does not align the same rule as the normal usage of "auto"?

What I expect is that for the first "auto", the `decltype(v)` should be the type of **const int** rather than **int&** like the second one since I do not specify a "&" beside "auto. So, any special rules for "Structured Binding" with "auto"?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int x{};
  const auto [v] = std::tuple<int&>(x); // v -> int&;
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(v), int&>);

  int& rx = x;
  const auto c = rx;  // c -> const int;
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(c), const int>);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: note that `int&&` with `const` qualifier applied is still `int&&`  (`const` is not something that makes sense for a reference so any attempt to add it has no effect)   . Qualifiers don't "dig down" past levels of reference/pointer.  You can see this with `using T = int&&;  const T t = 10;`

Comment: @M.M Hi, so why cv-qualifier does not make any sense for a reference? what are the related principles from the c++ design point of view?

Comment: Re "structured binding with `auto`", note a structured binding must always use `auto`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
  const auto [v] = std::tuple<T>(x);
```

The type `decltype(v)` is `T const`, i.e. `const`-qualified `T`. If `T` is `int`, then `decltype(v)` is `int const` (which also may be written `const int`). If `T` is `int&&`, then `decltype(v)` is `int&& const` which is `int&&` (not `const int&&` which is a reference to `const int`). The type `int&& const` is the same as `int&&` because references are always effectively `const`. The objects they refer to may be mutable, but references themselves in C++ are immutable.

With template type deduction without universal references, you cannot mimic this type transformation (add `const` to `T`) as far as I can tell. But there is a type transformation trait `std::add_const_t<T>`.

---

Update for Doubt 2

The structured binding

```
const auto [v] = std::tuple<int&>(x); // v -> int&;
```

is not analogous to

```
int& rx = x;
const auto c = rx;  // c -> const int;
```

It is instead analogous to

```
const auto e = std::tuple<int&>(x);
auto&& v = std::get<0>(std::move(e));
```

The const qualification applies to the tuple, not to the binding of v. The reference qualifier or lack of it applies to the tuple. The binding of v is **always** reference-like.

The oddness is actually in the other case:

```
const auto [v] = std::tuple<int>(x);
```

Still v is reference-like, but `decltype(v)` is `int`. The difference is that bindings in structured bindings are aliases, not references. They are different names for the things referred to, but don't themselves have reference types.

So:

```
const auto [v] = std::tuple<T>(x);
```

is most analagous to:

```
const auto e = std::tuple<T>(x);
auto&& r = std::get<0>(std::move(e));
(introduce v as a name for that which r refers to)
```

where that third line is not something we have the ability to write.

Comment: I updated the question and added some comments regarding the usage of "auto" with "Structured Binding". Do you know any difference between these two scenarios of using "auto"?

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff Garret mentioned, `const` will apply to the entire `auto` type deduced.  If the type is `int&`, for example, then `const auto` will be the same as `auto const`, which is the same as `int& const`.  The reference is `const`, not the data.

Now, what can you do about this?  You don't have to stop using `auto`.  You can simply specify `const auto&`.  `auto` will deduce to `int`, and the whole type will be `const int&` (equivalently `int const&`).  This is how you get your data to be const.